# Explain ${var:-val} and ${var+val}

Tags: sh

Can any one explain this format?

```
${name:-$devi}
```

Example:

```
      "${1+"$@"}" will check for that first variable to be set , if not it will use that 

        command line argument.
```

What is the difference between `:-` and `+`  between those variables?

Comment: Have you tried reading the man page? I'm not sure I could explain it any better.

Comment: it's just a part in a code which i was referring.i could't get the difference between those  ":-" and "+" in that representation.

Comment: i got the solution , ${variable:?word}   Complain if undefined or null         |
|${variable:-word}   Use new value if undefined or null         |
|${variable:+word}   Opposite of the above          |
|${variable:=word}   Use new value if undefined or null, and redefine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
${var:-val}
```

is the same as `${var}` if `var` is set and non-null, otherwise it expands to `val`. This is used to specify a default value for a variable.

```
${var+val}
```

expands to nothing if `var` is unset, otherwise it expands to `val`. This is used to supply an alternate value for a variable.

```
"${1+"$@"}"
```

is a workaround for a bug in old shell versions. If you just wrote `"$@"`, it would expand to `""` when no arguments were supplied, instead of expanding to nothing; the script would then act as if a single, empty argument had been supplied. This syntax first checks whether `$1` is set -- if there's no first argument, then there are obviously no arguments at all. If `$1` is unset, it expands to nothing, otherwise it's safe to use `"$@"`.

Most modern shell versions don't have this bug, so you can just write `"$@"` without the special check. I'm not sure if there are any other common use cases for the `+` construct in shell variable expansion.